# "Sections" going to full when adding a new div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to make things easier by having the ability to call functions, instead of having to use different JS files. So what I did was merge the files together into one, and wrap each one individually in a function. Then you can simple call them using `function()` instead of swapping in between of files. My first two effects work fine, but when wrapping the 3rd section I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null `

So with a bit more investigation I saw that I didn't have  `<div class="colors"></div>` in the HTML file. So what I then did was add it when the function was called using `document.getElementsByClassName('top').innerHTML = '<div class="colors"></div>';`. Unfortunately this didn't work for some reason. And now the sections all load, when the page loads. Here's my JS:

```
function sections(){
function cback(e) {
var t = [];
for (var n = inputs.length; n--;) {
    if (!inputs[n].value.length) t.push(inputs[n]);
}
var r = t.length;
var i = inputs.length;
var s = document.querySelectorAll(".top");
for (var o = s.length; o--;) {
    s[o].style.width = 100 - r / i * 100 + "%";
}
}
var forms = document.querySelectorAll(".form"),
inputs = [];
for (var i = forms.length; i--;) {
var els = forms[i].querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select");
for (var j = els.length; j--;) {
    if (els[j].type != "button" && els[j].type != "submit") {
        inputs.push(els[j]);
        els[j].addEventListener("input", cback, false);
    }
}
}

function generateCSSGradient(colours) {
var l = colours.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) colours[i] = colours[i].join(" ");
return "linear-gradient( to right, "+colours.join(", ")+")";
}

var cols = [
["#1ABC9C","0%"],
["#1ABC9C","33.3%"],
["#EC7063","33.3%"], // note same percentage - this gives a crisp change
["#EC7063","66.6%"],
["#3498DB","66.6%"],
["#3498DB","100%"]
];
document.querySelector(".colors").style.background = generateCSSGradient(cols);
document.getElementsByClassName('top').innerHTML = '<div class="colors"></div>';
var window_width = window.innerWidth + "px";
document.querySelector(".colors").style.width = window_width;

};
```

And I added this additional CSS which does the width and height

```
.colors{
width: 100%;
height: 4px;
}
```

I'm not really sure why this is happening. [Here's](http://jsbin.com/wuvelesi/1) a demo of the issue, and [here's](http://colourity.github.io/sections/) one of my actual working demo, but its the file way, not function. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gradient is a `div` contained in yet another `div` the inner one hold the color, the outer one limits the width; you dynamically adjust the width, but there is actually a slight difference between your two versions and it has nothing to do with the code you posted ;-)

```
.top {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is the only reason, why your colored strip is visible from the beginning. Add it to your new version and you should be fine.

Comment: Guess I missed that. Thanks for being a great help ;)